# How to Invoke function when clicked in cloud function firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a react native app and in the order, details screen its contain one button when I click it I want to call a function that's will send a notification to a specific device I have his FCM so how to handle these, I don't want to trigger the real-time database just click and calling,

## orderDetails.js

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => // here i want call function i wrote in index.js so?} >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 17 }}>Completed</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

## index.js

```
exports.sendN = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    try {
            const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload);
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        }
        return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Callable functions as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), or call the HTTP function directly from your Android code as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). The client-side JavaScript code in the latter case will just be calling a regular HTTP URL, so any any result from [this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+call+URL) should be a good starting point. This one is a bit old, but not bad: [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)